# Make a vertical bar reaching both the top and bottom of a page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a vertical bar to split the sidebar and the main-section.

I employed the grid bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-2 left-sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bootstrap</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>

    <div class="col-md-10 main-section">
        ....
    </div>
<div>
```

the css code:

```
.left-sidebar {
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image]

I found the official docs of [Bootstrap 4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) has a nicely structured left-side.

How to produce a vertical var reaching both the top and bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below snippet to get the equal height columns to your bootstrap grid.

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.row-eq-height > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.left-sidebar {
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #ccc;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-2 left-sidebar">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10" style="height: 100vh">
    some more content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boostrap4 main difference from BS3 is that it's using `flexbox` instead of `floats`. And with `flexbox` you can make columns inside a row have equal height. So you could make 2 columns and if the main-column will have for ex `1000px` height, the left column will have that height as well.

See snippet

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-section {
  height:200vh;
  background: blue;
}

.left-sidebar {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 left-sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bootstrap</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10  col-xs-10 main-section">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

IF you want to have the same effect as the one from the BS4 docs, then the left column has the height of the screen. You can do that with `viewport` units. And it also has `position:sticky`.

See below ( for some reason in the code snippet position:sticky doesn't work, check it here - > **[jsfiddle sticky](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/78227/)** )

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-section {
  height:200vh;
  background: blue;
}

.left-sidebar {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  height:100vh;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 left-sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bootstrap</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10  col-xs-10 main-section">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```